# Calling a function from custom directive on click? - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm calling a function from my custom directive on button click.

This is the code I've in my JSP

```
<input type="button" value="button" text="{{item.id}}" data-href="divSlide" show-notifications>
```

This is my custom directive

```
    hello.directive("showNotifications", ["$interval", function($interval, $scope) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {            
            //On click
            $(elem).click(function() {
                console.log('before');              
                scope.$parent.getJSON(scope.text);
               if ($('tr#' + $(this).data("href")).is(":visible")) {
                    $('tr#' + $(this).data("href")).remove();
                } else {

                    console.log('after');
                    $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr id="' + $(this).data("href") + '"><td colspan="5">' + $('#' + $(this).data("href")).html() + '</td></tr>');                    
                }    
            });
        },
        scope:{
            text: "@text"
        }
    };
}]);
```

And this is my function

```
$scope.getJSON= function(id){
        jsonService.getJSONData(id).then(function(data){
            $scope.data= [];                
                $scope.data= data['dataList'];
                console.log('insidejson');              
            }
           });
    };
```

When I execute the code the console prints the logs in the below order,

```
before
after
insidejson
```

But ideally it should be

```
before 
insidejson
after
```

Why is it executing the next statement after the function call before the function gets executed?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$.getJSON` is async. You need to wait for it to finish. return the promise from `getJSON` and do `scope.$parent.getJSON().then(....)`.

Comment: as a side note, there is probably a cleaner way to do what this directive is doing in angular without resorting to jquery....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the promise and use it:

```
$scope.getJSON= function(id){
  return jsonService.getJSONData(id).then(function(data){

$(elem).click(function() {
  var $element = $(this);
  console.log('before');
  scope.$parent.getJSON(, scope.text).then(function() {
           if ($('tr#' + $element.data("href")).is(":visible")) {
```

Note that `this` would no longer point to the element within the function. So I assigned it to a variable and already wrap it into a jQuery element. I also suggest that you pass the function to the directive:

```
<input type="button" show-notifications call="getJson">
```

And in your directive:

```
scope:{
        text: "@text",
        call: "="
    },
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {            
        //On click
        $(elem).click(function() {
            console.log('before');              
            scope.call(scope.text).then(...
```

Comment: Now the execution is right order but am not able to get the dynamic row in the view which is in the if else loop..


                    $('tr#' + $(this).data("href")).remove();
                
                    $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr id="' + $(this).data("href") + '"><td colspan="5">' + $('#' + $(this).data("href")).html() + '</td></tr>');                    
                }

Comment: @kumareloaded You are right, I forgot that `this` no longer points to the element. The most straightforward solution is to assign it to a variable and use that one instead of `this`. I have updated the code.

Comment: Yes thanks I've figured it out but I've another problem here now. The call to getJSONData sets the scope with data "$scope.data" which I'm using to populate my div and then append the div as a new tr with the data onClick. But the data is set only when the button is clicked twice and not the first time? :(

Comment: @kumareloaded That probably has to do with the digest cycle. Try to call `scope.apply()` before the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`jsonService.getJSONData` is async call, so the code continue after this line:   `scope.$parent.getJSON(, scope.text);` without waiting to `$scope.getJSON` answer.

to solve it, you can use `$q` service.
just add `$q` service and use `$scope.getJSON` function like this:

```
$scope.getJSON= function(id){
         var deferred = $q.defer();
        jsonService.getJSONData(id).then(function(data){
               console.log('insidejson'); 
                deferred.resolve(data);           
            }
           });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

And:

```
  $(elem).click(function() {
         console.log('before');              
         scope.$parent.getJSON(scope.text).then(function(data){
               if ($('tr#' + $(this).data("href")).is(":visible")) {
                        $('tr#' + $(this).data("href")).remove();
                    } else {
                        console.log('after');
                        $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr id="' + $(this).data("href") + '"><td colspan="5">' + $('#' + $(this).data("href")).html() + '</td></tr>');                    
                    }    
                       });

                });
```

Now all the code nested in the `then` and it will execute after the function `getJSON` will resolve the data with this line  `deferred.resolve(data);`

Comment: When I do this, the lines inside if else loop is not working, am not able to see the new row getting dynamically created on button click? why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

the function

```
   jsonService.getJSONData(id).then(function(data){
        $scope.data= [];                
            $scope.data= data['dataList'];
            console.log('insidejson');              
        }
       });
```

is an async function. hence it will execute in the end